# JUnit checked exception test

Tags: java, junit

I have the following test:

```
@Test(expected = ParseException.class)
public void parserTest4() {
    MeticParser.run("send+me-more=money");
}
```

Note that this test **must not** be changed.(Its from a test class given from my University)
My problem is that the `ParseException` is a checked exception so it must eiter be surrounded with `try/catch` or a `throws` statement must be added to the methode head.

Using `try/catch` JUnit wont see a `ParseException`  being thrown.

Using the `throws` signatur will result in me changing the test class (not allowed) since it must be given upwards until its being handeld.

Is there a workaround of some sort?

Comment: You have so far only described what you are not allowed to do. But what are you supposed to do? What is your assigned task?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to add a throws clause with the checked exception. JUnit expects exceptions to be thrown from tests, it catches the exception, saves the stacktrace, and marks the method as failed.

This isn't something to work around.  If you're not allowed to change it, your instructor should. Show your instructor that the test doesn't compile.